# How can I solve this exponential equation? I would study statistical mechanics but it stops me from going on.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x+b}{x-b}=e^a$$

We wrote down the solution in class but I don't seem to know how the solution is calculated. It's bugging me very much.

I would very much appreciate an answer that explains how it's solved.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which variable are you solving for?

Comment: For x. a, b are constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^a$ is just a number. Multiply both sides by $x-b$ to get $x+b = e^a (x-b)$. Then, collect like terms by subtracting $b$ from both sides, then subtracting $e^a x$ from both sides, to get $x - e^a x = - e^a b - b = - (e^a + 1) b$. Then, divide both sides by $1-e^a$ (noting that hte left hand side is $(1-e^a) x$) to get $x = \frac{ - (e^a +1)}{1-e^a} b = \frac{e^a+1}{e^a -1} b$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{x+b}{x-b}=e^a\\\\
\Rightarrow\quad& x+b=e^a(x-b)\\\\
\Rightarrow\quad&  x+b=e^ax-e^ab\\\\
\Rightarrow\quad&  x-e^ax=-b-e^ab\\\\
\Rightarrow \quad& x(1-e^a)=-b(1+e^a)\\\\
\Rightarrow \quad& x=-\frac{b(1+e^a)}{1-e^a}\tag{Assuming $1-e^a\neq 0$}\\\\
\Rightarrow \quad& x=\frac{b(1+e^a)}{e^a-1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

So, assuming $b\neq0$ (because $1-e^a\neq 0\Rightarrow e^a\neq 1$), the solution is
$$x=\frac{b(1+e^a)}{e^a-1}=\frac{b}{e^a-1}+\frac{be^a}{e^a-1}$$

Notice that the hypothesis $1-e^a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$ can be summarized as $b(1- e^a)\neq 0$ or $(e^a-1)b\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $a$ & $b$ are constant hence one can very easily solve for $x$ by separation as follows $$\frac{x+b}{x-b}=e^a$$
$$x+b=xe^a-be^a$$
$$xe^a-x=be^a+b$$
$$x(e^a-1)=b(e^a+1)$$
$$x=\frac{b(e^a+1)}{e^a-1}$$